# bootstrap 4 collapse only one at a time doesn't work. but works in bootstrap 3

Tags: bootstrap-accordion

I'm working with bootstrap 4.4.1. My goal is to expand accordion one panel at a time and close other panels which are previously open. I couldn't achieve this. I noticed one more issue, that my goal is achieved when bootstrap 3.3.1 is used. I mean accordion open one panel at a time is working in bootstrap 3.3.1, but not working in 4.4.1.

Bootstrap 4.4.1

```html
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion1">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" data-target="#collapseOne1">
             <h4 class="panel-title">Collapsible Group Item #1</h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" data-target="#collapseTwo1">
             <h4 class="panel-title">Collapsible Group Item #2</h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" data-target="#collapseThree1">
             <h4 class="panel-title">Collapsible Group Item #3</h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Bootstrap 3.3.1

```html
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion1">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" data-target="#collapseOne1">
             <h4 class="panel-title">Collapsible Group Item #1</h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" data-target="#collapseTwo1">
             <h4 class="panel-title">Collapsible Group Item #2</h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" data-target="#collapseThree1">
             <h4 class="panel-title">Collapsible Group Item #3</h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Is it feasible to achieve this on bootstrap 4.4.1?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `data-parent="#accordion1"` property to **div#collapseOne1**, **div#collapseTwo1** and **div#collapseThree1** instead of your divs with class **panel-title**.

[working example on codepen](https://codepen.io/milidubey/pen/xxzpxxa)

You can also add `class="accordion"` to your wrapper (div#accordion1) and use cards to style your accordion. [Refer to accordions](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/collapse/?#accordion-example)

```html
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion1">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse"  data-target="#collapseOne1">
      <h4 class="panel-title">Collapsible Group Item #1</h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne1" class="panel-collapse collapse show" data-parent="#accordion1">
      <div class="panel-body">Body 1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo1">
      <h4 class="panel-title">Collapsible Group Item #2</h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo1" class="panel-collapse collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" >
      <div class="panel-body">Body 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse"  data-target="#collapseThree1">
      <h4 class="panel-title">Collapsible Group Item #3</h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree1" class="panel-collapse collapse" data-parent="#accordion1">
      <div class="panel-body">Body 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```